# Draw Straight line between two points in vertical orientation using Opencv and C++

Tags: opencv, image-processing, line

I have tried to draw a straight line using two reference points and I got some problems on vertical orientation.

That's the current source code:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(600,600,CV_8UC3);
cv::Point p1(306,41);
cv::Point p2(304,8);

cv::Point p(0,0), q(img.cols, img.rows);
if (p1.x != p2.x) {
    double m = (double) (p1.y - p2.y) / (double) (p1.x - p2.x);
    double b = p1.y - (m * p1.x);
    p.y = m * p.x + b;
    q.y = m * q.x + b;
} else {
    p.x = q.x = p2.x;
    p.y = 0;
    q.y = img.rows;
}

cv::circle(img, p1, 4, cv::Scalar(255,0,255), -1);
cv::circle(img, p2, 4, cv::Scalar(255,0,255), -1);
cv::line(img, p, q, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
```

This is the following output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess `cv::line(img, p1, p2, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);` is not what you want, right?

Comment: Hi @Miki, I want a full line crossing the image and using the p1 and p2 points as references.

Comment: In this case, the points p and q should be the final points of line.

Comment: Your code works well for me... please double check

Comment: @Miki, I passed the wrong points. Please have a look on the following points: p1 = (301,49) and p2 = (303,460).

Comment: [Still good](http://imgur.com/Ps5QTim)

Comment: Unbelievable! I got [this result](http://imgur.com/Hn89H0m)

Comment: I posted an answer with the code I used...please try it. Maybe you have problems in parts of the code you aren't showing

Comment: It turned out this was a bug. Please accept the new answer with the reference to the fixed bug.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of you running on the 2.4.9 version. Given the Miki anwser it might have been fixed on newer versions.

The problem seems to happen when the line slope is too high and therefore the intersection with the y axis it is far away from the origin.

I tested the cited point,as well many others and the following function handled that problem. It basically computes the intersection of the computed line with the image borders and return collinear points in the image borders.

```
void getLinePointinImageBorder(const cv::Point& p1_in, const cv::Point& p2_in,
                               cv::Point& p1_out, cv::Point& p2_out, 
                               int rows, int cols)
{
    double m = (double) (p1_in.y - p2_in.y) / (double) (p1_in.x - p2_in.x + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());
    double b = p1_in.y - (m * p1_in.x);

    std::vector<cv::Point> border_point;
    double x,y;
    //test for the line y = 0
    y = 0;
    x = (y-b)/m;
    if(x > 0 && x < cols)
        border_point.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));

    //test for the line y = img.rows
    y = rows;
    x = (y-b)/m;
    if(x > 0 && x < cols)
        border_point.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));

    //check intersection with horizontal lines x = 0
    x = 0;
    y = m * x + b;
    if(y > 0 && y < rows)
        border_point.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));

    x = cols;
    y = m * x + b;
    if(y > 0 && y < rows)
        border_point.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));

    p1_out = border_point[0];
    p2_out = border_point[1];
}
```

Comment: The @Diego's solution worked to me. I tested using a set of points and it gave the correct line points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce the error with your code. This code (copied & pasted from yours) works well:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(600,600,CV_8UC3);
    cv::Point p1(301,49);
    cv::Point p2(303,460);

    cv::Point p(0,0), q(img.cols, img.rows);
    if (p1.x != p2.x) {
        double m = (double) (p1.y - p2.y) / (double) (p1.x - p2.x);
        double b = p1.y - (m * p1.x);
        p.y = m * p.x + b;
        q.y = m * q.x + b;
    } else {
        p.x = q.x = p2.x;
        p.y = 0;
        q.y = img.rows;
    }

    cv::circle(img, p1, 4, cv::Scalar(255,0,255), -1);
    cv::circle(img, p2, 4, cv::Scalar(255,0,255), -1);
    cv::line(img, p, q, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I asked one friend to run this code and he got the same results than me. =S

Comment: What is your opencv version? Did you perform it in linux/window/mac?

Comment: Opencv 3.2 visual studio 2015 (vc14) 64bit, win10

Comment: I have performed on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits, Opencv 2.4.13.

Comment: I was not doubting about your results, but it is really funny that the same source code present two different outputs. Do you have some tip about that, if we have a version problem?

Comment: It's very unlikely to be a bug... My best bet is that you either made a _very stupid_ mistake (no offence ;) ), or you have setup problems (did you used release libraries in debug or viceversa?). However, you can try to install OpenCV 3.2 and see if this works

Comment: @sturkmen please post it as an answer, so we can close the case

Comment: @Miki could you please add information to your answer. i have no time to post an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4555), now fixed.

So update to the latest version of OpenCV (version 3.2) or use `cv::clipLine(img.size(), p, q);` before drawing line.

---

All credits to [@sturkmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5294258/sturkmen)

Comment: Thanks Miki and sturkmen for all!